# How to remove get started in umbraco dashboard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, umbraco

I found an answer to remove get started in the umbraco dashboard is by adding this code to composer.

```
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Dashboards;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.DependencyInjection;

namespace Umbraco.Docs.Samples.Web.Dashboards
{
    public class RemoveDashboard : IComposer
    {
        public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Dashboards().Remove<ContentDashboard>();
        }
    }
}
```

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/dashboards/

I build the umbraco project using command "dotnet new umbraco". Where should i put the composer file? I am using umbraco 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to place the file anywhere, as long as you rebuild after? And remember to change the sample to actually remove the Get Started dashboard and not Content dashboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

To update Jannik's answer for Umbraco 11, I found that in my project "Getting Started" dashboard was the `ContentDashboard` class

```
builder.Dashboards().Remove<ContentDashboard>();
```